# add a class to iframe and select that class to display iframe

Tags: jquery

i have a jquery code that creates iframes base on how many records the code finds, a button that onclick re size the iframe, what i am trying to do is add a class to the iframe, so that i can only show the iframe the click on. this is the code that i have, but it keeps showing all the iframes

```
$("<iframe />" , {
        src: strTest,
        id: "myframe",
        width: '100%'       

    }).appendTo('.content');
    $("<button/>", {
      align: "center"
    })
    .text("Select Patient")    
    .click(function () { $("#myframe").attr("Height", "125%").addClass("selectedIframe"); }).appendTo('.content');
    $(".selectedIframe", window.parent).show();
  $("<hr />").appendTo('.content');
}
```

can somebody help me or point me to the right direction thanks

Comment: Suggestion: Use `on` for event binding on dynamically created elements `.on('click',function () { $("#myframe")..`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a unique ID for each frame. Currently your code appears to always create the frames with the same id - `myframe`

You might be able to frig it by using `$(this)` on this line of code:

```
$(this).attr("Height", "125%").addClass("selectedIframe");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to add the class when you create the iframe:

```
$("<iframe />" , {
        src: strTest,
        id: "myframe",
        width: '100%'       

    }).appendTo('.content').addClass("selectedIframe");
```

instead of where you are doing it now (in the click handler).

Answer (score 0):

You can add stuff like classes and content when you create the element, and if you use variables you can reference the elements in later functions :

```
var iframe = $("<iframe />" , {src    : strTest, 
                               id     : "myframe", 
                               width  : '100%', 
                               'class': 'myIframe'
             }),
    button = $("<button />", {style: 'margin: 0 auto; position: relative',
                              text : 'Select Patient'
             });

$('.content').append(iframe, button);

button.on('click', function() {
    iframe.css({height: '125%'}).addClass('selectedIframe');
});

$(".selectedIframe", window.parent).show();
$("<hr />").appendTo('.content');
```

Notice that `class` used this way should be quoted, as it's a reserved javascript keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try use onClick :

```
var iframe = $("<iframe />" , {src    : strTest, 
                               id     : "myframe", 
                               width  : '100%', 
                               onclick: function(){ $(this).addClass('myIframe'); }
             }),
    button = $("<button/>", {style: 'margin: 0 auto; position: relative',
                             text : 'Select Patient'
             });

$('.content').append(iframe, button);

button.on('click', function() {
    iframe.css({height: '125%'}).addClass('selectedIframe');
});

$(".selectedIframe", window.parent).show();
$("<hr />").appendTo('.content');
```

Comment: This looks somewhat familiar ?

Comment: yes but when i click the button it still shows the other iframes

Comment: @user1766952 Are you give the other iframes the same class "selectedIframe"?